# Unprotect and Append Excel Worksheets from Multiple Workbooks to a New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've multiple (around 400) protected (with the same password) excel files and each have a common worksheet, named "Survey Summary". I want to copy and append the data of that worksheet (from a specific column to the end of data) from all the workbooks to a new excel workbook. I've used the below VBA code. Unfortunately, it's showing run time error-1004 which shows that "Excel can't access 'TSSR Approved'. The document may be read-only or encrypted."

Please help.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "F:\Nokia_BD\BanglaLink Project\TSSR\TSSR_Approved\Approved TSSR Complete"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = Workbooks.Open("F:\Nokia_BD\BanglaLink Project\TSSR\TSSR_Approved\Approved TSSR Complete")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Survey Summary_Total")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Copy data on "Survey Summary" sheet to "Survey Summary_Total" Sheet in other workbook
    With wb.Sheets("Survey Summary")
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A3:Q" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End With

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks
Sajib

Answer (score 0):

If your files are password protected, you also need to fill in the password when opening them: `Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filename, Password:=Password`